# Java Buffered Reader splitting file into segments of 7 lines separated by #

Tags: java, string, arraylist, line, bufferedreader

```
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
        String line;
        boolean justWrote = false;

             ArrayList<String> charRead = new ArrayList<String>();
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                 if (charRead.size() == 7 && !justWrote){
                     messageLoop.addAfter(charRead);
                     justWrote = true;
                 }
                 else if (line.startsWith("#")) {
                 }
                 else {
                 justWrote = false;
                 charRead.add(line);
                 }
             }
```

I am utilizing a text file that stores 7x5 ArrayLists that store a representation of a character. In the loading function I am attempting to create a bufferedreader for the file and then while ignoring lines that start with #, store the lines 7 at a time into an ArrayList of Strings and then add this ArrayList into the existing data structure.

Basically what needs to happen is:
Read whole file until end
When 7 lines are read in a row, add the ArrayList of Strings into the data structure and reset ArrayList to be look for next 7 lines
If the line contains ########## ignore it
IF line is valid and we don't already have 7, add the line to ArrayList

The issues I am having is it is correctly going through and adding all the lines ignoring the ######## but it keeps going through even when it reaches the end so I end up with hundreds of lines instead of just what I need. The input file looks like

```
  XXX 
 X   X
 X   X
 XXXXX
 X   X
 X   X
 X   X
########## 
 X
 X
 X
 X
 X
 X
 XXXXX
##########
 X
 X
 X
 X
 X
 X
 XXXXX
##########
```

And it should produce that same output when it is printed in the program but it instead prints multiple instances and the characters are not separate. Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Should produce the same characters but without ######### and just a space instead (spaces are handled already in code just represents the characters being separate.)

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question that the goal is more clear? Do you want to print out all correct 7x5 letters from text file?

Comment: Yes, I have a large text file of Strings on each line, after every 7 lines there is a line designed to separate the groups and is ########. The program needs to find 7 lines and convert these 7 lines into an ArrayList<String> type and then add this ArrayList to an object. ####### means that the next 7 lines are coming.

Comment: What if you have only 5 lines before the separator?

Comment: That case can be assumed to never occur. It will always be 7 lines of useful info then a line of pound symbols.

Comment: Is it a requirement to create Reader? Or can you simplify it?

Comment: Also can you just re-print the contents of the file except separator or is it a requirement to read letters into internal data structures?

Comment: It is not a requirement, simply seemed like the easiest way for me. The only things that remain constant are the need the text file to be read and converted into ArrayList<String> objects that contain 7 useful lines to be utilized later. Also they must be read into internal data structures cannot be reprinted.

Comment: You might want to provide the printing code in case the bug is in the printing code rather than in the reading code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go with data structures here. In particular you'd need one for a Letter.
Then read letters one by one 7 characters to the letter, ignoring # symbol.
Here is how you could do it in Java 7:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadLetters {
    static final int ROWS = 7;
    static class Letter {
        private final List<String> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addRow(String row) {
            rows.add(row);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String result = "";
            for (String row : rows) {
                result += row + System.lineSeparator();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<Letter> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        Letter current = new Letter();
        int rowCount = ROWS;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/the/file"))) {
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith("#")) {
                    current.addRow(line);
                    if (--rowCount <= 0) {
                        letters.add(current);
                        current = new Letter();
                        rowCount = ROWS;
                    }
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        for(Letter l : letters) {
            System.out.println(l);
            System.out.println("------");
        }
    }
}
```